# How to add more than one item to a UITableViewCell 's contentView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I've got a fairly complex UITableViewCell and in production code I'm able to pull out a selected UILabel with the following

```
[[[[[[cell subviews] objectAtIndex:1] subviews] objectAtIndex:0] subviews] objectAtIndex:4];
```

Everything works no problem -the issue I'm having is when I try to create a simple unit test that shows how this is expected to work.

For some reason I'm not able to build up a scenario that has 2 items in the contentView property of the cell

So I can easily get [[cell subviews] objectAtIndex:0] but never 1

In my test helper I'm doing the following to simulate this (with no luck)

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc] init];
UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
UIView *view2 = [[UIView alloc] init];
UILabel *label2 = [[UILabel alloc] init];

[view1 addSubview:label1];
[cell.contentView addSubview:view1];

[view2 addSubview:label1];
[view2 addSubview:label2];
[cell.contentView addSubview:view2];

NSLog(@"inside ...%@", [[cell subviews] objectAtIndex:1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't add label1 to view1 AND view2, you have to create two different labels. One view can ONLY have one superview so when you say `[view2 addSubview:label1];` then label1 gets removed from view1.